# Proof of $\partial A = \bar A $ \ $A ^\circ$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let (X,d) be a metric space and let  A $\subset$ B.
How to prove that $\partial A = \bar A $ \ $A ^\circ$ where $ \bar A$ denotes the closure of A and $A^\circ$ denotes the interior of A ?

Comment: What is your definition of "boundary"?

Comment: The usual definition given (other than this difference of sets) is $x \in \partial A$ iff every neighborhood of $x$ intersects both $A$ and $A^c$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, use the definition of $\partial A$ to show that if $x \in \partial A$, then $x \in \overline A$, but $x \notin A^\circ$.

Then, suppose that $x$ is in $\overline{A} \setminus A^\circ$. Because $x \in \overline{A}$, every neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A$.  However, because $x \notin A^\circ$, no neighborhood of $x$ lies entirely in $A$.  Conclude that $x \in \partial A$.